# java.lang.System.arraycopy (Native Method) freezes CPU cores

Tags: java

We have a web app build with JSF1.2, Richfaces 3.3.2SR1 in a CentOS 5.5 with kernel java: 1.6.020, and java 1.6.20 running a tomcat 6.0.20.

Days ago, java just starts to freeze, using a entire core of CPU, forcing us to do a ugly `kill -9` in the java process.

I got the following exception.

```
Feb 1, 2012 5:04:19 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl phase
WARNING: phase(RESTORE_VIEW 1,com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl@fea29c) threw exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException null
java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest.fillBuffer(MultipartRequest.java:396)
org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest.initialize(MultipartRequest.java:600)
org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest.parseRequest(MultipartRequest.java:616)
org.richfaces.component.FileUploadPhaselistener.beforePhase(FileUploadPhaselistener.java:63)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:215)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:113)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:244)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:367)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
......
```

I think that the fileupload are generating this exception some way, but, I dont know how to solve...

I do a lot of research, and the only [link I found is this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-7927?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel#issue-tabshttps://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-7927?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel#issue-tabs), and it isnt useful at all.

Someone else ever seen this before? I just dont know what to do, and I dont want to update all the things in a production server...

Does anyone have a solution? Is there a java bug or something?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: And what have you changed or done before it started to freeze?

Comment: Can you connect to the server with something like JVisualVM or the java console during the CPU spike, and get a thread dump to make sure which method is causing it?

Comment: nothing was changed, it just start to freeze... about the JVisualVM, i will take a look tomorrow with my boss..

Comment: According to the bug report which you linked yourself (which was, in contrary, very useful), it has been fixed in RichFaces 3.3.3. Did you upgrade?

Comment: hmm, that's true @BalusC, I will try it, maybe tomorrow. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just upgrade the RichFaces version to 3.3.3 and now everything works fine. Thanks.